# How to call generic trait method in Rust

Tags: rust

Having these rather contrived type definitions

```
trait Generic<T> {
    fn some(&self) -> T;
}

impl<T> Generic<T> for i32
where
    T: Default,
{
    fn some(&self) -> T {
        T::default()
    }
}
```

I would like to call `some` method explicitly specifying type T. Below code apparently does not work because the method itself is not generic.

```
fn main() {
    let int: i32 = 45;
    println!( "some: {}", int.some<bool>() );
}
```

What's the right way of calling `some`?

Comment: Compiler is not able to infer since `println!` macro accepts generic type. Here is some ideas : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8f59a103f21f101be18b1e5e0805d644

Comment: @ÖmerErden Great answer! But why is that `&int.some() as &bool` works while `int.some() as bool` does not?

Comment: You can't directly cast `T` into a target type, please see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must specify the exact type, as you tried. Unfortunately, your function is not generic, and instead your implementation is generic, so you'd have to do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let int: i32 = 45;
    println!("some: {}", <i32 as Generic<bool>>::some(&int));
    // Or,
    println!("some: {}", Generic::<bool>::some(&int));
}
```

Alternatively you could define a helper trait:

```
trait HasSome {
    fn other_some<T>(&self) -> T where Self: Generic<T> {
        <Self as Generic<T>>::some(self)
    }
}
impl<T> HasSome for T {} // Blanket impl.
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e5c322d7408cfc261d1d61d942c3353).

---

On a side note, please know that when specifying the generics of a type or function you need to use the "turbofish" `::<>` operator:

```
let foo = Vec::<i32>::new(); // Vec<i32>
let foo = my_generic_function::<usize>(); // Calls my_generic_function with usize
let foo = Option::<usize>::None;
let foo = None::<usize>;
```